# How can I define arguments of variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using, type-alias

I have a variadic template and would to define the arguments using `using` alias declaration.

Here is an example:

```
template<class I, class... P>
struct Molecule {
  using Index = I;
};
```

My question is, how can I define the first argument of `P...` ?

I have already tried this, but it generates an error:

```
template<class I, class... P>
struct Molecule {
  using Index = I;
  P array[sizeof...(P)] = { P... };
  using Part1 = array[0];
};
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Redefine your `Molecule` as `template<class I, class First, class... P>`.

Answer (score 3):

> how i can define the first argument of P... ?

If the `Molecule` can be redefined to the following, you get it directly:

```
template<class I, class First, class... P> { 
    using Part1 = First;
    // .....
}
```

Otherwise, make a trait to find the first type:

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest> 
struct first { using type = First; };
template<typename... Args> using first_t = typename first<Args...>::type;
```

Now

```
template<class I, class... P> struct Molecule {  
    using Part1 = first_t<P...>; // first type
};
```

assuming that you would have at least one argument in variadic `P...`.

**[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xYzd6E486)**